# WaitForExit() Runtime Exception. (Waiting for cmd process to finish)

Tags: vb.net, process, cmd, exit

Can you kindly tell me why I am getting a runtime exception when trying to run this code?

```
Sub BtnNowClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim myProcess As New Process
    Dim processFile As String = dlgFolder.SelectedPath
    Dim pyLocationDel As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dlgFolder.SelectedPath)

    myProcess.Start(pyLocationDel) 
    myProcess.WaitForExit()     
    System.IO.File.Delete(pyLocationDel)


End Sub
```

Basically, what I want, is to detect for a process to be finished and delete a specific file if the process is finished.

I'm getting this error when trying to execute the code:

```
   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lgaPDF.MainForm.BtnNowClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\student3\My Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\lgaPDF\lgaPDF\MainForm.vb:line 184
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at lgaPDF.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you never create any `Process` instance.

You can use the constructor when you declare the varaible:

```
Dim myProcess As New Process()
```

With a separate constructor call:

```
Dim myProcess As Process
myProcess = New Process()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, I tried it but I'm getting a new error `System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.`

Comment: You can't junk somebody's answer like that.  Start a new question.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm sorry but I did not understand. Should I start a new question?

Comment: @Martin Ok Sorry.. for next time then :) Now, I updated the code and I'm getting the error message described earlier.