# Runtime Error when executing WaitForExit()

Tags: vb.net, process, cmd, delete-file, waitforexit

I'm trying to execute the following code, but the debugger is failing at  `myProcess.WaitForExit()`

```
Sub BtnNowClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim myProcess As Process
    Dim processFile As String = dlgFolder.SelectedPath
    Dim pyLocationDel As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dlgFolder.SelectedPath)

    myProcess.Start("pdfmerge.py") 
    myProcess.WaitForExit()     
    System.IO.File.Delete(pyLocationDel)


End Sub
```

Basically, what I want, is to detect for a process to be finished and delete a specific file if the process is finished.

I'm getting this error when trying to execute the code:

```
   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lgaPDF.MainForm.BtnNowClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\student3\My Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\lgaPDF\lgaPDF\MainForm.vb:line 184
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at lgaPDF.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
```

Comment: This question has already been answered. If you have any problem with the changed code, you have to post the changed code.

Comment: @Guffa Hey, I had updated the code and posted the new error message but another user told me to post a new question regarding the new problem!

Comment: You posted the same code again, not the updated code.

Comment: @Guffa I updated some of the code and the error message, as I told you, I was asked to start a new question since it wasn't related with the original question.

Comment: Yes, the new question should contain the updated code, not be a copy of the original question. As you see below, you only get the same answer as for the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET - WaitForExit() Runtime Exception. (Waiting for cmd process to finish)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227830/vb-net-waitforexit-runtime-exception-waiting-for-cmd-process-to-finish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub BtnNowClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim processFile As String = dlgFolder.SelectedPath
    Dim pyLocationDel As String = Path.Combine(dlgFolder.SelectedPath, "pdfmerge.py")

    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dlgFolder.SelectedPath)

    Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start("pdfmerge.py") 
    myProcess.WaitForExit()     
    System.IO.File.Delete(pyLocationDel)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myProcess As NEW Process
```

myprocess is only declared, never instantiated

Comment: When I try that I get this error message: `System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.`